# Don't know how to get the discord user access_token, refresh_token and profile with the next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

hey folks I have written this next-auth function to enable discord authentication in my webpage

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord';

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: 'identify email guilds applications.commands.permissions.update'
                }
            },
            token: "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token",
            userinfo: "https://discord.com/api/users/@me", 
        }),
    ],
})
```

but my problem is I don't know to log `access_token`, `refresh_token` and profile please help me in this

Comment: You should be able to access token data in the [`jwt` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback).

Comment: don't worry I have  fixed this issue but can you look up to the previous question in which I asked about pop window I mean how can I fix that issue as you find the issue why the window was closing immediately